# Flutter firestore set data and get document ID

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the newly created document when posting a new item into firestore.

I know there are other similar questions and I tried them! BUT not getting the output that I was hoping for.

So basically, I `set` a bunch of data and then I do `doc().id` within `then` and it returns an id that does not exist in my firestore nor does it match any of my created documents.

code:

```
return _userRef.doc(_user.uid).collection(collName).doc().set({
      'item_name': name,
      'item_description': description,
      'item_location':
          GeoPoint(_locationData.latitude, _locationData.longitude),
      'item_date': DateTime.now(),
      'item_images': imageMap,
    }).then((value) {   
      print('${_userRef.doc(_user.uid).collection(collName).doc().id}');
    });
```

I saw another question where they did :

```
 var ref = _userRef
              .doc(_user.uid)
              .collection(collName)
              .get()
              .then((value) => print('hello ***** ${value.docs[0].id}'));
```

but this just returns the first document in the list of documents! I was thinking of loading one array before the `set` and then load a 2nd array after the `set` and then just compare the 2 arrays and find the odd man out. BUT that would take a very long time if I have a huge list!

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 1):

[doc()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html) with no parameters creates a [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) with a random ID.  If you want to know that ID, it's immediately available in that object's `id` property.  You can access it right away without having to write anything.

```
var ref = _userRef.doc(_user.uid).collection(collName).doc();
print(ref.id);
```

The ID is generated in the client app, which is why it's immediately available.  The document won't actually exist until you call `set()` on that reference.

```
ref.set(...);  // after success, the document will exist
```

Comment: thank you, but what I want to know is how to get that newly created document after the set. what I did in the mean time is load an array before the set, then I loaded a second array after the set, so now the before should have the same list as the after except the after array will have 1 element more than the other, that 1 element is my newly created doc. I got it to sort of work....

Comment: You will have to `get()` the document normally using that same reference.  There is no shortcut for that.  `set()` will not return you the new contents of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use add method for adding new documents to your collection.

```
Firestore.instance.collection(collName).add({
      'item_name': name,
      'item_description': description,
      'item_location':
          GeoPoint(_locationData.latitude, _locationData.longitude),
      'item_date': DateTime.now(),
      'item_images': imageMap,
    });
```

Then you can see the document you added on your collection and get its id by that way.

Comment: how do I see the document that I added? Let's say I have 30 documents. I go add another one, how do I tell my program to go fetch that specific newly created document?